# Stop/resume/restart functionality in countdowntimer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdowntimer

I have incorporated a countdowntimer in an html5-game I am currently working on using the following javascript lib.

https://cdn.rawgit.com/robbmj/simple-js-countdown-timer/master/countdowntimer.js

```
window.onload = function () {
var display1 = document.querySelector('#time1'),
    display2 = document.querySelector('#time2'),
    timer1 = new CountDownTimer(5),
    timer2 = new CountDownTimer(10);

timer1.onTick(format(display1)).onTick(restart).start();
timer2.onTick(format(display2)).start();

function restart() {
    if (this.expired()) {
        setTimeout(function () { timer1.start(); }, 1000);
    }
}

function format(display) {
    return function (minutes, seconds) {
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.textContent = minutes + ':' + seconds;
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robbmj/vpq5toeq/4/

Is there any way I can stop/resume and restart the timer using the above mentioned library.

Answer (score 0):

The library you linked to does not provide any pause or stop functionality.

It would be relatively simple to add some form of pause/resume functionality as the library is only a few lines long.  Probably something along the lines of an instance variable called `paused` and `pause()` & `resume()` methods.